# no aparecen los datos de un select cuando se usa apend para clonar un bloque de html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un formulario, el cual cuenta con una parte que se clona con un boton(uso .append), es decir, me aparece esa informacion las veces que el boton sea oprimido. Dicho bloque clonado, cuenta con un select de opciones que trae la informacion desde una base de datos.

Asi se ve el primer bloque, que tiene el select con la informacion.

[image: asi se ve el primer bloque, que tiene el select con la informacion.]

Y la segunda imagen es como se ve el bloque clonado.

[image: Y la segunda imagen es como se ve el bloque clonado.]

Al clonar esa parte del formulario, no me trae los resultados en el select, alguien me puede decir como puedo hacer eso?

Adjunto codigo:
HTML:

```
<div class="botones">
                    <div role="group" class="btn-group-sm btn-group btn-group-toggle right mb-4" data-toggle="buttons">
                        <button type="button" id="masActividades"  class="btn btn-primary">+
                        </button>
                        <input type="button" id="cantActividades" value="" class="btn btn-primary disabled">
                        <button type="button" id="menosActividades" class="btn btn-primary">-
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="">
                    <label><h6>Actividades 1</h6></label><br>
                    
                    <div class="position-relative row form-group"><label for="formFecha" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Fecha</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9"><input name="" id="formFecha" placeholder="with a placeholder" type="date" class="form-control"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="position-relative row form-group"><label for="formParticipantes" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Participantes</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9"><textarea rows="3" name="" id="formParticipantes" placeholder="Participantes..." class="form-control"></textarea></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="position-relative row form-group"><label for="formLugar" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Lugar</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9"><input name="" id="formLugar" placeholder="Lugar..." type="text" class="form-control"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="position-relative row form-group"><label for="formReferencia" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Referenciar programa</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <select id="formReferencia" class="form-control">
                            <option value="">Seleccione un programa</option>
                            
                        </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="position-relative row form-group"><label for="formTematica" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Temática abordada</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9"><textarea rows="5" name="" id="formTematica" placeholder="Observaciones..." class="form-control"></textarea></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="clonActividad">
                </div>
```

JS:

```
$("#masActividades").click(function(){
                // cont += 1;
                
                var cont = $(".form-actividad").length + 2;
                $("#clonActividad").append("<div class='form-actividad' id='bloqueDeActividad'>"+
                                                "<label><h6>Actividades "+cont+"</h6></label><br> " +
                                                "<div class='position-relative row form-group'><label for='formFecha"+cont+"' class='col-sm-3 col-form-label'>Fecha</label>"+
                                                    "<div class='col-sm-9'><input name='' id='formFecha"+cont+"' placeholder='with a placeholder' type='date' class='form-control'></div>"+
                                                "</div>"+
                                                "<div class='position-relative row form-group'><label for='formParticipantes"+cont+"' class='col-sm-3 col-form-label'>Participantes</label>"+
                                                    "<div class='col-sm-9'><textarea rows='3' name='' id='formParticipantes"+cont+"' placeholder='Participantes...' class='form-control'></textarea></div>"+
                                                "</div>"+
                                                "<div class='position-relative row form-group'><label for='formLugar"+cont+"' class='col-sm-3 col-form-label'>Lugar</label>"+
                                                    "<div class='col-sm-9'><input name='' id='formLugar"+cont+"' placeholder='Lugar...' type='text' class='form-control'></div>"+
                                                "</div>"+
                                                "<div class='position-relative row form-group'><label for='formReferencia' class='col-sm-3 col-form-label'>Referenciar programa</label>"+
                                                    "<div class='col-sm-9'>"+
                                                        "<select id='formReferencia' class='form-control'>"+
                                                            "<option value=''>Seleccione un programa</option>"+
                                                        "</select>"+
                                                    "</div>"+
                                                "</div>"+
                                                "<div class='position-relative row form-group'><label for='formTematica"+cont+"' class='col-sm-3 col-form-label'>Temática abordada</label>"+
                                                    "<div class='col-sm-9'><textarea rows='5' name='' id='formTematica"+cont+"' placeholder='Observaciones...' class='form-control'></textarea></div>"+
                                                "</div>"+
                                            "</div>");
                $("#cantActividades").val(cont);
    
        });


    
        $("#menosActividades").click(function(){

            var cont = $(".form-actividad").length;
            $("#clonActividad #bloqueDeActividad").last().remove();
            
            $("#cantActividades").val(cont);
        });
```

Asi lleno el select:

```
function getSelectProgram() {
    $.ajax({
        url: url_base+'api/programas',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {          
            var datosArray= data;
            // console.log(datosArray);
            
            var container1 =$("#formReferencia");
            var container2 =$("#formPrograma");
            // var container3 =$("#referenciaEditarFormPP");
            for (i = 0; i < datosArray.length; i++){
                let id =datosArray[i].id;
                let nombrePrograma =datosArray[i].descripcion;

                container1.append(

                    "<option data-id='" + id + "'>"+ nombrePrograma +"</option>"

                );
                container2.append(

                    "<option data-id='" + id + "'>"+ nombrePrograma +"</option>"

                );
            }
            
        }
    });
}
getSelectProgram();
```

Comment: Que versión de jQuery estas utilizando?

Comment: @Nor jQuery v1.11.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando haces click en tu botón, veo que haces un append de un div con su contenido y te hace el clon del select. Pero en ningún momento después haces la llamada ajax para llenar tu select. Es decir.

Primero haz esto:

```
$("#masActividades").click(function(){
                // cont += 1;
                
                var cont = $(".form-actividad").length + 2;
                $("#clonActividad").append("<div class='form-actividad' id='bloqueDeActividad'>"+
                                                "<label><h6>Actividades "+cont+"</h6></label><br> " +
                                                "<div class='position-relative row form-group'><label for='formFecha"+cont+"' class='col-sm-3 col-form-label'>Fecha</label>"+
                                                    "<div class='col-sm-9'><input name='' id='formFecha"+cont+"' placeholder='with a placeholder' type='date' class='form-control'></div>"+
                                                "</div>"+
                                                "<div class='position-relative row form-group'><label for='formParticipantes"+cont+"' class='col-sm-3 col-form-label'>Participantes</label>"+
                                                    "<div class='col-sm-9'><textarea rows='3' name='' id='formParticipantes"+cont+"' placeholder='Participantes...' class='form-control'></textarea></div>"+
                                                "</div>"+
                                                "<div class='position-relative row form-group'><label for='formLugar"+cont+"' class='col-sm-3 col-form-label'>Lugar</label>"+
                                                    "<div class='col-sm-9'><input name='' id='formLugar"+cont+"' placeholder='Lugar...' type='text' class='form-control'></div>"+
                                                "</div>"+
                                                "<div class='position-relative row form-group'><label for='formReferencia' class='col-sm-3 col-form-label'>Referenciar programa</label>"+
                                                    "<div class='col-sm-9'>"+
                                                        "<select id='formReferencia' class='form-control'>"+
                                                            "<option value=''>Seleccione un programa</option>"+
                                                        "</select>"+
                                                    "</div>"+
                                                "</div>"+
                                                "<div class='position-relative row form-group'><label for='formTematica"+cont+"' class='col-sm-3 col-form-label'>Temática abordada</label>"+
                                                    "<div class='col-sm-9'><textarea rows='5' name='' id='formTematica"+cont+"' placeholder='Observaciones...' class='form-control'></textarea></div>"+
                                                "</div>"+
                                            "</div>");
                $("#cantActividades").val(cont);

            // aquí que entiendo que es donde estás clonando tu select,
            // debes llamar a:
            getSelectProgram()
           
        });
```

Si no nunca te va a llenar el select desde la DB.

Espero haberte guiado, un saludo y suerte

Comment: Muchas gracias! solucionado

Comment: Me surgio un problemita que no se como resolver. Al agregar mas actividades, se duplican y triplican los datos en los select, de casualidad sabes que podra ser?

Comment: @CaroS. Quizás al insertar, si lo haces con ajax también, estás haciendo llamadas recursivas a la misma función que te llena los select